# Azure Function throws error when triggering from Swift code without much explanation and fails

Tags: python, swift, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am building an iOS app with Azure Functions, and I have been stuck with a function, which doesnt seem to be executing. I reduced the function to the basics like this, but I am still getting an error.

This is the Python code:

```
@app.route(route="sent_chat_msg", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def sent_chat_msg(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    current_time = "hi"

    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=json.dumps({"success": True, "date": current_time}),
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )
```

And this is the Swift code:

```
func sendChatMsg(msg: Message?, userMail: String, completion: @escaping (Message?,String?, Bool?) -> Void) {
        let url = "api_url.com/sent_chat_msg?code=mycode"
        var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
        if let message = msg {
            parameters["sender"] = userMail
            parameters["message"] = message.message ?? ""
        }
        print("parameters: \(parameters)")
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    print("data: \(data)")
                    if let httpResponse = response.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                            print("Chat message sent successfully")
                            if let dataDictionary = data as? [String: Any], let dateString = dataDictionary["date"] as? String {
                                print("dateString: \(dateString)") // This should print "hi"
                                let new = Message(sender: msg!.sender, message: msg!.message,dateString: dateString)
                                completion(new,dateString, true)

                            }

                        } else {
                            print("Failed to send chat message")
                            completion(nil, nil,false)
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Unexpected response format")
                        completion(nil, nil,false)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(nil, nil,false)
                }
            }
```

Here is the Azure function output:

`2024-03-20T12:25:23Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.sent_chat_msg' (Failed, Id=78a3571c-d56d-4362-838b-a0d1c4326c08, Duration=108ms)`

And here is the Swift output:

`parameters: ["sender": "something", "message": "helohiwhatsup"] Error: Response could not be serialized, input data was nil or zero length. success: Optional(false)`

What am I doing wrong?

I started with lots of code in the azure function, but as you can see, I removed all of them basically. I've tried running new pipelines, and I am not sure whats wrong. I have other functions exactly set up like this, and they work perfectly.

Comment: 1. Did you build and deploy your function app using Azure DevOps pipeline? If so, is there any error message in the pipeline? 2. What's the result if you build and deploy your app from your local machine?

Comment: Ahh sorry, forgot to tell. The python code is being built and deployed by Azure DevOps pipeline. There are no messages at all during the building, the deployment is successful. The only error in Azure is the one I included as Azure function output in the post. The iOS app is not being built by azure devops at all as of right now. In my local machine, the python code works perfectly.

Comment: You can deploy your function app from your local machine using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli) and check if there is the same issue. If there isn't, you will need to check if there is anything missing in the pipeline. If there is, it seems to be some issues with the response.